# How to prove there exists a bijective map from $\gamma(t)$ to $\beta(t)$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

$\gamma(t) = (w_1(t),w_2(t),...w_m(t))$  and $\beta(t) = (v_1(t),v_2(t),...v_m(t))$ are two curves where

$$\frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt} = -g(\gamma(t))$$
$$\frac{d\beta(t)}{dt} = -\frac{g(\gamma(t))}{\Vert g(\gamma(t))\Vert_2}$$

$g: R^m \rightarrow R^m$, $\gamma(0)=\beta(0)$. 
Is it possible to show there exists a bijective map T s.t. $T(\gamma(t)) = \beta(t)$ so that these two curves follow the same path. I believe these two curves have different speeds but can have the same path. I don't know how to deal with the norm.

Or is there any theorem discuss it? Thank you.

Comment: No. I'd better use another notation to avoid confusion.

Comment: so it is $\gamma$ in the RHS of the second equation?

Comment: Yes, I just normalize the speed.